# Set up proxy on selenium geckodriver

Tags: c#, selenium, geckodriver

I'm having issues adding proxy support to my geckodriver selenium program.

```
                var proxy = new Proxy();

            if (useproxies == true)
            {
                if (proxytype) //True = SOCKS5
                {
                    /*var proxy = proxies[proxyindex];
                    profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
                    profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks", proxy.Split(':')[0]);
                    profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", proxy.Split(':')[1]);
                    */
                    proxy.SocksProxy = proxies[proxyindex];
                    if (proxyindex >= (proxies.Count - 1)) { proxyindex = 0; } else { proxyindex++; }
                }
                else //False = HTTP
                {
                    proxy.HttpProxy = proxies[proxyindex];
                    if (proxyindex >= (proxies.Count - 1)) { proxyindex = 0; } else { proxyindex++; }
                }
            }
            //user agent
            profile.SetPreference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0");

            //start
            options.Proxy = proxy;
            options.Profile = profile;
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

But this isn't working, I already tried a lot of ways, but none is working for me. Anyone knows how to do this? First time working with geckodriver, I always use chromedriver.

EDIT: In answer to @AtachiShadow , the issue remains.

```
                var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
            var options = new FirefoxOptions();

            //proxy
            if (useproxies == true)
            {
                if (proxytype) //True = SOCKS5 | False = HTTP
                {
                    try
                    {
                        profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
                        profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks", proxies[proxyindex].Split(':')[0]);
                        profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_port", proxies[proxyindex].Split(':')[1]);
                        profile.SetPreference("network.proxy.socks_version", 5);
                        if (proxyindex >= (proxies.Count - 1)) { proxyindex = 0; } else { proxyindex++; }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        WriteConsole("Proxies.txt is bad... Exiting.");
                        Console.Read();
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    try
                    {
                      if (proxyindex >= (proxies.Count - 1)) { proxyindex = 0; } else { proxyindex++; }
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        WriteConsole("Proxies.txt is bad... Exiting.");
                        Console.Read();
                        Environment.Exit(0);
                    }
                }

            }
            //user agent
            profile.SetPreference("general.useragent.override", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:69.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/69.0");

            //start
            options.Profile = profile;
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Same issue with your sugestion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I enable proxy socks in my browser with the following commands (this is Python 3 code):

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile(ub_profile)
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.type', 1)  # int
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.socks', '111.11.11.1')  # string
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_port', 12345)  # int
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_version', 4)  # int
browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
```

And there is a difference with your code. You probably don’t indicate which version of the proxy socks you have:

```
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_version', 4)  # When you have proxy version 4
```

or

```
fp.set_preference('network.proxy.socks_version', 5)  # When you have proxy version 5
```

And yet, I enable proxies through `.FirefoxProfile()`, and not through `.Options()`.

Try it like this.

Comment: Does the browser load at all without a proxy in the settings? Is it possible to view the contents of the `about:preferences` page? Or maybe there are some more messages from the browser or console about this?

Comment: Ok @AtachiShadow , so I just noticed something strange, it does indeed load the proxy if I go to about:preferences, but the port remains 0. If I change the port manually to the right one, the proxy works. I don't know why network.proxy.socks_port is sending port 0. I'm gonna try to send it as a int instead of a string, maybe that's it?

Comment: Yep @AtachiShadow, I had to send the port as a int, it's now working perfectly, thanks!

Comment: I am happy for you, but I specifically commented on these parameters in the code of my answer, the data types that are needed)))) Look at the first block of code in my answer)

Comment: ye, I just noticed haha. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I was happy to help)